# Onsen UI with Jquery

Tags: jquery, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm new with Onsen UI. I am trying to use it with Jquery, but examples in internet are very few. I have an index.html page with a single slide menu. It has a main page(which is a list page where each item is like a menu) wiht a navigator. When i click in any item i push the corresponding page in the Navigator. I want to access the buttons(using jquery) from the ons.ready function o manipulate the content from any part of my app.js.

How could i do this?

This is my index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ons-sliding-menu var="app.slidingMenu" menu-page="menu.html" main-page="main.html" side="left" type="overlay" max-slide-distance="200px"></ons-sliding-menu>
    </body> 
</html>
```

main.html

```
<ons-navigator title="Main Navigator" var="app.mainNavigator" ons-postpush="manageNav" id="mainNavigator">
   <ons-page>
       <ons-toolbar> </ons-toolbar>
       <ons-list>
           <ons-list-header>My Option</ons-list-header>
               <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="app.mainNavigator.pushPage('myoption.html',{animation: 'slide'});">
               </ons-list-item>
       </ons-list>
   </ons-page>
```

myoption.html

```
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
            <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Title</div>
        <div class="right">
            <ons-button onclick="goHome();">Home</ons-button>
        </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item>
             <input id="txtName" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="text-input text-input--underbar" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
<div class="content-padded" style="text-align: center">
    <ons-button id="mybutton" onclick="">A button</ons-button>
</div>
```

I want to know how to access "mybutton" and access from goHome() to any component of my pages using jquery, all this in my app.js file. Must i set up that in ons.ready function?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may use angularJS to access the button and fire goHome() function.

html

```
<div class="right" ng-controller="MyOptionController">
    <ons-button ng-click="goHome();">Home</ons-button>
</div>
```

angularJS

```
myApp.controller('MyOptionController', function () {
    ons.ready(function () {
        $scope.goHome = function () {
            //your code
            app.mainNavigator.popPage({animation: 'slide'});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question asks solution with JQuery. Is is impossible?